# Infinite sets' partition. And their cardinality.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

What has to be proven is:
*If $\mathit X$ is any infinite set, then there exists two disjoint subsets $\mathit Y$ and $\mathit Z$ of $\mathit X$ such that$|\mathit X|$=$|\mathit Y|$=$|\mathit Z|$ and $\mathit X$=$\mathit Y \cup\mathit Z$.*

I have used contrapositive to successfully proved the existence of A to be subset of an infinite set X such that A and its complement set A$^c$ on X to be both infinite, which is $\bf {if}$ for all subset of X, say A, A or its complement A$^c$ are finite, $\bf then$ X is finite.
It suffices to prove that there exists A such that cardinality of A and A$^c$ to be same. Since by cardinal arithmetic, |X|=|A$\cup$A$^c$|=|A|+|A$^c$|=big one in {A,A$^c$}. If I proved the existence of such an A, then it follows that |A|+|A$^c$|=|A|=|A$^c$|,which indicates |A|=|A$^c$|=|X|, then proof can be finished. However, I have no idea how to prove the existence of these two sets whose cardinality are the same. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: What do you know on set cardinals? In particular do you know that for an infinite set $X$, $X$ and $X \times X$ have the same cardinal?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net this is a very nice solution

Comment: Yes, for sure. And I know aleph0 to the power of aleph0 is the cardinals of real numbers, by cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: @HamioJiang Since $|X \times X| = |X|$ it suffices to prove the claim on $X \times X$. On this set a solution might be a little more clear using your observation about compliments.

Comment: @basket Thanks man, it seemed that I got some clues.

Comment: At some point you must use the Axiom of Choice, as it has been shown to be equiconsistent with the other axioms (ZF) of set theory that the proposition is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So suppose that $\varphi : X \times X \mapsto X$ is a bijection. Take $a \in X$. Then $Y=\varphi[X \times \{a\}]$ and $Z=\varphi[X \times (X \setminus \{a\})]$ answer your question.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks. It seems that my start point is not correct.